# How to insert xml text & value in html option text & value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I want to insert a `option` tag with text and value from reading `xml` tags.

Here I want to insert `<option value> Text</option>` like this way below:

**`<option value[from each xml col1]> Text [from each xml col2] </option>`**

Here is the code:

```js
var xml = ' <row id="1_2"> <col1>46.0</col1>   <col2>Acting Allowance</col2> </row> <row >            <col1>A1</col1> <col2>Allowance for 65 years plus</col2></row>',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);


$xml.find('col2').each(function () {
    var option = $(this).text(), //i want to take text from each col2 as option text  
        value = $(this).attr('value'); //i want to take text from each col1 as option value  
    $("#selectID").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + option + "</option>");
});
```

```html
<select id="selectID"></select>
```

Please let me know for further information. Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? Note that `<col2>` doesnt' have a  value ?

Comment: @adeneo  thanks.I saw that  col2 doesn't have value.But i just want its the  text (not value) of col1 as a Value for `<option >` tag and text (not value) of col2 as a Text for `<option >` tag.thanks

Comment: might work better if you use `<row>` in your `find` action and the grab `value/text` from either `<col1/col2>`

Comment: Thanks @RST .can you please show me this  on the given snippet.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `XML` was invalid. You have to insert any root node (I just was wrapped the xml with `<root>` node.

```js
var xml = '<root><row id="1_2"><col1>46.0</col1><col2>Acting Allowance</col2></row><row><col1>A1</col1><col2>Allowance for 65 years plus</col2></row></root>',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);


$xml.find('row').each(function() {
  var row = $(this),
      option = row.find('col2').text(), //i want to take text from each col2 as option text  
      value = row.find('col1').text(); //i want to take text from each col1 as option value

  $("#selectID").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + option + "</option>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectID"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mosh Feu the option tag text works. But i want the value from col1 Not from col2 .can you help me on this.thanks

Comment: I was updated my answer. See if that's what you need.